# Run Spark official python machine learning example on Yarn failed

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, machine-learning, hadoop-yarn

I can run the pi.py example on yarn successfully by: `./bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster examples/src/main/python/pi.py`.

But when I run `./bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster examples/src/main/python/ml/logistic_regression_with_elastic_net.py` , failed. Error message: `Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1`

By comparing these two file, I found after add this `from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression` to `pi.py`, run `pi.py` failed too.

But I don't know how to fix it. And I have another quetion: When I run the ml example I have to upload my own data file to hdfs, So I try to use `--files`, is it right? If it's right, Since I dont't know the path of the data file on hdfs, the python script can't get the data file. (I can see the path after the file is uploaded to hdfs, i.e. `hdfs://master:9000/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1488329960574_0011/mnist8m_800`but it's too late, can I specify the path when I submit?)

Comment: What version of spark are you using?

Comment: @Mariusz spark 2.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run **logistic_regression_with_elastic_net** you need to upload sample libsvm data to HDFS like this:

```
$ hdfs dfs -mkdir -p data/mllib
$ hdfs dfs -put data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt data/mllib
```

Then example will work with both yarn-client and yarn-cluster modes.

As far as I know files uploaded by `--files` cannot be read using spark session (like in regression example).

Comment: My purpose is to upload data file while submit. And I saw this `--files A list of files to be placed in the working directory of your application. This can be used for data files that you want to distribute to each node.`  on the book **Learning Spark**.  @Mariusz

Comment: Yes, you can use `--files` to pass addidional files that can be read in pure python. But libsvm data here are treated as input file and when running on YARN it is read in parallel by executors. That's why you need to put it on distributed storage.